# How to properly implement NSCollectionView in swift4?

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

can you check what's wrong with my codes? I can successfully run the application but with empty content. Thanks!

```
import Cocoa

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        self.initView()
        self.initCollectionView()
    }

    func initView() {
        let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "NavCollectionViewCell"), bundle: nil)
        //ßßself.collectionView.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "NavCollectionViewCell"))
        self.collectionView.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: .collectionViewItem)
    }

    func initCollectionView() {
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension MainViewController: NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        // 4
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: .collectionViewItem, for: indexPath)
        return item

    }
}

extension NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
    static let collectionViewItem = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("NavCollectionViewCell")
}
```

Comment: In your code there is no content.

Comment: @vadian I'm loading a nib with labels as content. What do you think am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, in my definition content is a string assigned to a label, a picture assigned to an image view etc.

Comment: @vadian, I'm sorry I don't get it. Can you  post the necessary function that I need to add? This is my first try in macOS development. Thanks!

Comment: If you are new to the stuff why are you using the hard / advanced way (extra nib) rather than designing everything in the storyboard / main nib? Please read the [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145978/nscollectionview-tutorial) and the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html) The programming Guide is for iOS but the basics are the same.

Comment: @vadian My background is iOS Development. I'm just confused with the implementation of NSCollectionView compared to UICollectionView. I already read the Ray Wenderlick tutorial but it is written in swift 2.2, I'm writing code via swift4, xcode 9.2. Thanks for your help! Hopefully you can answer my previous question. Thanks

Comment: Also read the [documentation of `collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdatasource/1524271-collectionview?language=objc). It says "After receiving the item object, update its properties with the data from your app’s data structures".